# Search results using ajax in django

Tags: html, css, django

I am searching the products from the database using this[image] search bar, but as soon as this search bar shows me results the header(dark blue area)part also expands along with the search results something like this[image]. I want when search results are shown the header should not expand, the search results should go over the header. My search box code is like this-

```html
<div class="search_box">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            <ul id="search-results" class="list-group">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

i am using django with ajax, so i am displaying my search result like this-

```html
{% if p1.count > 0 %}
    {% for p in p1 %}
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/products/product_info/{{p.id}}/">{{p.productname}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
<li>None to show!</li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The styling has nothing to do with ajax and django. It would be the same as if you wrote the html by hand. If you help with styling, you have to show us the actual css and html produced. You probably have to set a width to `.form-group` and have both the search input and the list inherit from the parent container's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should apply the styling `position:absolute` to your `li` elements.

Comment: Thanks, it worked more correctly when i added this in ul tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the list items `<li>` are added to the header area. A solution to this would using a typeahead.js or JQuery Autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add class "navbar-form" to form tag. Then, replace class "form-group" to "input-group".

```
<div class="search_box">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            <ul id="search-results" class="list-group">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```